# How to establish a SSH connection in Python

Tags: python, ssh

I am using Python 3.6.6 and i need to establish a SSH connection to a server.

I have the IP and port for the server, and i use my credentials to login, usually through putty. The servers is on Linux/Suse . 
I need to get the list of directories in the server folder, and copy the content of one of the files out. I am using paramiko, and i need the connection to be open so i can execute and interact with the server. 
I am not sure i am clear enough.

Below is my code

```
import paramiko 

nbytes = 4096
hostname = '123.123.123.123'
port = 22020
username = 'uname' 
password = 'pwd'
command = 'vi log'

client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)

stdout_data = []
stderr_data = []
session = client.open_channel(kind='session')
session.exec_command(command)

while True:
    if session.recv_ready():
        stdout_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
    if session.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
    if session.exit_status_ready():
        break

print ("rec status: ", session.recv_ready())
print ("exit status: ", session.recv_exit_status())
print ("".join(stdout_data))
print ("".join(stderr_data))

session.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: "Unable to access the list of files" isn't very informative. If you care to elaborate, that would be helpful.

Comment: please show us your paramiko code snippet.

Comment: the command `vi log` will open you an interactive vi session on the file called `log`. I guess that's not what you want. For file transfers using paramiko, you should have a look at sftp instead of using `exec_command`: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html